# Numpy savetxt format issue

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am converting a dataframe to a fixed width csv file using the following:

```
fmt='%2s%-10s%3s%1.0f%4s%1s%4.0f%2.0f%2.0f%4.0f%1s%1s%2.0f%2.0f%4.0f%16.0f%12.0f%5s' 
np.savetxt('df.txt',df.values,fmt=fmt)
```

The code runs fine except for cases where I have a single digit (i.e.%2.0f%2.0f%4.0f% refers to day, month, year).
If I have for example 7,3, 2017 it will output

```
 7 32017
```

I want

```
07032017
```

For a case like 10,10, 2017 it runs fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `'%0<pad>.<precision>f'` or `'0<pad>d'`

This is described in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html).

Example:

```
x = np.array([7, 3, 2017]) 
np.savetxt('out.txt', x, fmt='%02.0f')
```

Output in `out.txt`:

```
07
03
2017
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure the data type is integer, use `%02d%02d%04d` instead.